# Calculating absolute average in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe-

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'A':[33,-44],'B':[44,-66],'C':[66,21]})
```

I want to find the absolute average per row(ignoring the signs) and the formula for taking the average will be for example-

for the first row-

```
(33+ 44/2 + 66/3)/3 = 25.6
```

for second row-

```
(44+66/2+21/3)/3=24.3
```

This is not a direct average but according to a specific column the value will be divided by a specific value like for column A its 1 for column B its division by 2 and so on.

output-

```
        Average
     0  25.60000
     1  24.300
```

I did -

```
df[['average']]= (abs(df[['A']]).values + abs(df[['B']]/2).values +  abs(df[['C']]/3).values )/3
```

but its giving error

Comment: Your numbers doesn't add up. How does 77/3 result in 47.6?

Comment: @HenryYik thank you..I made a mistake in calculation

Comment: Use `df["average"] = (abs(df["A"])+abs(df["B"])/2 + abs(df["C"])/3)/3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is has error because:
they mistake that: `['average'] is in the index , ofcouse ['A'], ['B'] ,....` too .

You should try this:

```
df['average']= (abs(df['A']).values + abs(df['B']/2).values +  abs(df['C']/3).values )/3
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that possible with pd.Series?

```
((abs(df['A'])+abs(df['B']/2)+abs(df['C']/3))/3).to_frame()
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df["average"] = (df.abs()/np.arange(1,4)).mean(axis=1)
```

if there are more columns then:

```
df["average"] = (df[['A','B','C']].abs()/np.arange(1,4)).mean(axis=1)
```